# How to save file from HTML2PDFRocket to folder on Server

Tags: azure, pdf, async-await

My Azure Web app calls html2pdfrocket with this code:

```
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, stream.ToString());
```

But I get back an invalid PDF of just a few bytes. I know the URL I pass to html2pdfrocket is valid because I can paste it into their Website to test  it. Do I need to async/await or something else to get all the data before attempting to save it to a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use async/await, the `.Result` does the thing like await.

A similar error in your code, `stream.ToString()` only converts the stream object itself to a string, but does not contain the content.

I suggest you use byte[] array instead of stream(I did test with stream, but the saved .pdf file is empty even though the content length is correct).

Try use byte[] array like below, and it works at my side:

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("apikey","xxxxx"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value", "the url")
                });

                var result = client.PostAsync("http://api.html2pdfrocket.com/pdf", content).Result;

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {                    
                    // change the path as per your need
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\temp\0618.pdf", result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
                }
            }
```

Comment: This solution works! I should add that I had more than one problem. Another was some javascript in the page that was to be converted. The script, when the document was read, tried to copy some embedded base64 text to the src property of an image. That didn't work. So I removed the script and hardcoded the base64 string as the image src, and that worked fine.